# MSVC outputs loading dlls of opposite "bitness"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've been developing a project under Microsoft Visual C++ 2010, on a 64-bit machine, but I'm building both 32 and 64-bit binaries. When I attempt to run the output, I find that my 32-bit output ONLY loads dlls from SysWOW64, while my 64-bit build is loading from System32. This wasn't happening before.

I've kept all configuration options that I thought pertained to the "bitness" of the output in the appropriate settings (32-bit output for the win32 platform, 64-bit output for the x64 platform). Is there any setting that could cause this odd mixup? (It's very unclear to me where this kind of error could originate, but I'm not very experienced with Visual Studio, so I'm not familiar with many of the configuration settings).

Comment: *This wasn't happening before.* are you sure about that? Isn't the whole point of the SysWOW64 stuff to allow running 32bit applications on 64bit windows? - *this kind of error* what error exactly?

Comment: This is entirely normal, it has always worked this way.  Forcing the file system redirector to do it differently requires untrivial code that you never write by accident.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it wasn't causing a problem before. In any case, I ultimately solved the problem. My path included the 64-bit dlls before the 32-bit ones, so it was loading those up. It still seems to always load from the opposite-bitness directories, but it works properly now. Had to modify my path to put 32-bit dlls first.